# DropDownList – Opción “Todos"

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

Estoy llenando un `DropDownList` con un `ViewVag` que trae los registros de una base de datos. Este muestra solo los registros que el usuario actual tiene asignados y la opción `Todas`. En este caso devuelve las sucursales que el usuario actual tiene.

```
Usuario objCurrentUser = (Usuario)Session[Constantes.SESSION_USUARIO];
var sucList = objCurrentUser.Sucursales;

var listSucursales = sucList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.descripcion,
    Value = x.descripcion,
    Selected = x.descripcion.Equals("Todas")
});
ViewBag.sucursal = listSucursales;

//View 
@Html.DropDownList("sucursal", null, new { @class = "form-control", @title = "Seleccione..." })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando seleccione la opción `TODAS`, el listado muestre todos los registros de todas las sucursales que el usuario tiene asignadas.
Actualmente mi listado solo filtra por una sucursal específica. Uso este método:

```
var result = from i in myService.ventasClientesf
             where i.Sucursal.Equals(sucursal)
             select i;

ViewBag.resultado = result;
```

He intentado hacer lo siguiente, siguiendo las indicaciones de @Flxtr:

```
Usuario objCurrentUser2 = (Usuario)Session[Constantes.SESSION_USUARIO];

var sucList2 = objCurrentUser.Sucursales;
var result = from i in myService.ventasClientesf
             where i.Sucursal.Equals(sucursal == "Todas" ? sucList2 : sucursal)
                         select i;
```

Pero sale el siguiente error:

> type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' and String
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo de a clase `Sucursal` es el siguiente:

```
public partial class Sucursal
{
    public Sucursal()
    {
        Usuario = new List<Usuario>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string descripcion { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string codigoSap { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

    public List<Sucursal> listar()
    {
        var lista = new List<Sucursal>();
        try
        {
            using (var db = new PhartecContext())
            {
                lista = db.Sucursal.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);

        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como estas definiendo la cadena desde el método la cadena todas lo que puedes es hacer una comparación antes de entrar a la consulta.

algo como:

```
 if(Sucursal=="Todas")
 { 
 var result = rom i in myService.ventasClientesf.ToList();
 }
 else
 { 
 var result = from i in myService.ventasClientesf where i.Sucursal.Equals(sucursal) select i;
 }
```

Comment: Hola @Xique, lo habia pensado, pero lo que pasa es que si hago eso se mostrara todos los registros sin importar la Sucursal, incluyendo las sucursales que el usuario actual NO TIENE ASIGNADAS. Es decir si un usuario hace ventas en 3 sucursales (Sistema x). Pero en mi sistema el administrador solo le asigna 2 sucursales... el usuario al seleccionar Todas solo debe visualizar las ventas de esas dos sucursales. Si sigo tus pasos, mostraría incluso los registros de la sucursal q no le asignaron

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero que si seleccionan la opción todas, primero obtengas las sucursales asignadas de la misma forma que de un inicio haces para llenar la lista desplegable y se evalúe en las condiciones de la consulta ya sea por sucursal o por alguna seleccionada en específico.

```
List<string> sucursalesPorBuscar = new List<string>();
if(sucursal == "Todas")
{
    Usuario objCurrentUser = (Usuario)Session[Constantes.SESSION_USUARIO];
    var sucList = objCurrentUser.Sucursales;

    foreach(var item in sucList)
    {
        sucursalesPorBuscar.Add(item.Descripcion);
    }
}
else
{
    sucursalesPorBuscar.Add(sucursal);
}

var result = from i in myService.ventasClientesf
             where sucursalesPorBuscar.Equals(i.Sucursal)
             select i;
```

Comment: Hola @Flxtr, he trato de hacer lo que me indicas pero me sale el siguiente error : Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Model.Sucursal>' and String,

Comment: @DanielCarrascoZegarra una última pregunta en la comparación, deseas buscar las sucursales en el objeto `myService.ventasClientesf`, pero, ¿de qué tipo es `i.Sucursal`? ¿Es un `int` donde guardas el Id de la sucursal o es un `string` donde guardas la descripción?

Comment: Para la primera pregunta la respuesta es No, las sucursales no se encuentran en  myService.ventasClientes.Por otro lado  i.Sucursal (string) es un atributo que devuelve myService. Por último es un int donde guardo el ID de la sucursal (Modelo Sucursal), es por ello estoy tomando poniendo como valor la descripción.  `var listSucursales = sucList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.descripcion,
    Value = x.descripcion,
    Selected = x.descripcion.Equals("Todas")
});`

Comment: @DanielCarrascoZegarra entonces cómo buscas en la entidad `myService.ventasClientesf`? ¿Buscas a través del campo `Sucursal` cierto?

Comment: (edite el comentario) Para la primera pregunta la respuesta es No,las sucursales no se encuentran en  myService.ventasClientes.Por otro lado i.Sucursal (string) es un atributo que devuelve myService.Por último es un int donde guardo el ID de la sucursal (Modelo Sucursal), es por ello estoy tomando poniendo como valor la descripción `var listSucursales = sucList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.descripcion,
    Value = x.descripcion
});` Como ponía arriba Actualmente mi método si funciona, si filtra por sucursal ya que iguala el texto que recibe, con el texto de mySer...

Comment: he editado mi comentario

Comment: @DanielCarrascoZegarra dado que el campo `Sucursal` es un tanto ambiguo, he optado por crear una lista de `string`, con la cuál estarías buscando las sucursales que tiene asignada un usuario

Comment: Hola @Flxtr, siguiendo tus indicaciones al tratar de compilar me aparece el siguiente error **{"No se pudo convertir la expresión de constante System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] en cadena."}**

Comment: @DanielCarrascoZegarra creo que me faltó algo, edité esta línea `where sucursalesPorBuscar.Equals(i.Sucursal)`, revisad *my friend* ;)

Comment: Hola @Flxtr pero lo quiero es igualar la sucursa que recibo ´i.Sucursal´ a los items de ´sucursalesPorBuscar´. De igual forma hice  el cambio pero el error es el mismo

Comment: @DanielCarrascoZegarra con esa instrucción estarías igualando en caso de que se seleccione la opción Todas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo intentas buscar la sucursal de la base de datos cuando el usuario seleccione alguna especifica y en caso de que seleccione la opcion "todas" retornar las que tiene asignadas que se encuentran cargadas en una variable de session

por lo que sugiero algo asi:

```
Usuario objCurrentUser2 = (Usuario)Session[Constantes.SESSION_USUARIO];

var sucList2 = objCurrentUser.Sucursales;

var result = sucursal == "Todas" ? sucList2 : from i in myService.ventasClientesf                                                   
                                            where i.Sucursal.Equals(sucursal == sucursal)
                     select i;
```

En caso de que necesites buscar la lista de sucursales que tiene el usuario asignada en la base de datos sugiero que lo hagas con consultas lambda utilizando .Contains, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var sucList2 = objCurrentUser.Sucursales.Descripcion.ToList();

var result = myService.ventasClientesf.where(s=> sucursal == "Todas" ? sucList2.Contains(s.Descripcion) : s.Descripcion == sucursal).ToList();
```